# Unnecessary escape character warning

Tags: javascript, regex

This shows a warning of `Unnecessary escape character`. how do I resolve this.

```
    validateEmail = email => {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    };
```

Comment: React JS! anyways its solved by @Tim Pietzcker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one unnecessary escape, and that's `\[` within the character class:

```
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

You do need to escape the `]` because it would otherwise end the character class, but an opening bracket is only a metacharacter when it's not inside a character class.